# How does gazebo handle damping in Joint::SetForce?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using gazebo's API to apply force to a joint with a non-null damping coeficient (Defined in the SDF). Is it necessary to include the damping effect when I call the method SetForce() ?

e.g   joint -> SetForce ( 0, effort - joint->GetDamping(0) * joint->GetVelocity(0))

Or does Gazebo handle the damping automatically and I don't have to include it?

e.g   joint -> SetForce ( 0, effort )

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7642/how-does-gazebo-handle-damping-in-joint::setforce-?/) by [Eduardo Albuquerque](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/948/eduardo-albuquerque/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

No, you don't have to include the damping effect when you call `SetForce`. You shouldn't at least. If it's not working like this then [submit a bug report](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new) and we'll fix it.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1